# Magento 2 Product base image and thumbnail images are not showing!

Tags: product-images, thumbnail, magento2.3.1, gallery-image

Product images are not showing on product detailed page.

> Small images are showing on listing page but base images and thumbnail
>   images are not showing on the product page.

I have given 777 permission media folder. Issue after migration from magento 1.9 to magento 2.3.1

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to product edit page and resave. Is it showing now?

so you need:

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

Also:
Any errors in browser console? or system.log and exception.log?

Answer (score 0):

Delete attributes with the `no_selection` values using this SQL script:

```
DELETE `cpev_s`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` `cpev_s` JOIN `eav_attribute` `ea` ON `cpev_s`.`attribute_id` = `ea`.`attribute_id` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` `cpev_0` ON `cpev_0`.`row_id` = `cpev_s`.`row_id` AND `cpev_0`.`attribute_id` = `cpev_s`.`attribute_id` AND `cpev_0`.`store_id` = 0 WHERE `cpev_s`.`value` = 'no_selection' AND `ea`.`attribute_code` IN ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail') AND `cpev_s`.`store_id` > 0 AND `cpev_s`.`value` != `cpev_0`.`value` AND `cpev_s`.`value` = 'no_selection';
```

After, don't forget to flush cache

[Reference](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002446014-Product-images-are-not-displayed-although-set-on-the-Product-Edit-page)

Comment: I have run your query but there is no row affected in the database.

Comment: did you run deploy static files and then flush cache?

Comment: Yes, I have deploy static files.

Comment: @fmsthird, I am also facing similar issue here, please look into it,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277561/images-are-not-loading-after-upgrade-to-magento-2-3-0