# Images are not loading after upgrade to Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache

We have upgraded magento from 2.2.8 to 2.3.0

Upgrade is done correctly, But product images are not loading in list page and product detail page.

Right now the product images are taking like below

```
  site_url/media/catalog/product/cache/2765542505660baab28ecd555e27366e/t/m/image_name.jpg
```

which is going to 404 error.

Same url if i open like below by removing cache the image is loading

```
site_url/media/catalog/product/t/m/image_name.jpg
```

So, how can i change the code in list page, product page and all other pages to load the product image without from the cache folder through out the site.

I have run the upgrade, static content deploy and flushed the cache also.

Is there any fix available for this. I am using magento commerce edition in magento cloud.

Right now all product images are loading from media/catalog/product/cache folder, but all are returning 404 not found

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: category page or product detail page ?

Comment: @RkRathod, in both the pages..

Comment: ok  wait let me check

Comment: @RkRathod,sure thanks

Comment: @RkRathod, any suggestions? found anything?

Comment: @jafarpinjar did you try to refresh, flush cache cache then reindex

Comment: @fmsthird, i did all of them but no luck..

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue after upgraded to latest version of magento 2.3.2 I got this issue that is missing images on frontend and backend. It doesn't generate the cache in /pub/media/catalog/product/(empty) it shows.

So then try to use this command

**php bin/magento catalog:images:resize**

If it is done successfully your issue got resolved. Its regenerates the catalog product images.

It has upgrade issue in magento, I tried few of solutions from this link, You may get resolve your issue. Give a try on further information using below link

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19710

Good luck